# Rename WordPress admin URL wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to rename the admin URL 'wp-admin' to e.g. 'admin'.
I set a rewrite rule in the .htaccess to acces the admin login:
RewriteRule ^admin wp-admin [NC,L]

That works but I can still use /wp-admin.
So I have to tell Wordpress that 'admin' is the new URL.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You could present this question over at [The Official WordPress Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) but if I recall correctly, it's not recommended. Better to secure your login than rename it as there are a bunch of little problems that will pop up when doing so. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Solution without plugins:

Edit the .htaccess and add the code below between the *IfModule mod_rewrite.c* tags:

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ /wp-login.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Also edit the wp-config.php and add:

```
define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', 'admin');
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
```

Edit the functions.php file from your theme and add:

```
add_filter('site_url',  'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);
function wpadmin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ) {
   $old  = array( "/(wp-admin)/");
   $admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;
   $new  = array($admin_dir);
   return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}
```

And that's it! Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to install the [iThemes Security plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) (formerly Better WP Security).

Or follow [this easy 5-step guide](https://w3reign.com/how-to-change-wp-admin-url-in-wordpress-without-plugin/) on changing `wp-admin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin named [Move Login](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/sf-move-login/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Custom Admin Name Change 
Description: Change Url Link of Admin.
*/

if ( defined( 'ABSPATH' )
    && ! class_exists( 'Secure_Login' ) ) {

    class Secure_Login {

        private $wp_login_php;

        private function basename() {

            return plugin_basename( __FILE__ );

        }

        private function path() {

            return trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) );

        }

        private function use_trailing_slashes() {

            return ( '/' === substr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), -1, 1 ) );

        }

        private function user_trailingslashit( $string ) {

            return $this->use_trailing_slashes()
                ? trailingslashit( $string )
                : untrailingslashit( $string );

        }

        private function wp_template_loader() {

            global $pagenow;

            $pagenow = 'index.php';

            if ( ! defined( 'WP_USE_THEMES' ) ) {

                define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

            }

            wp();

            if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $this->user_trailingslashit( str_repeat( '-/', 10 ) ) ) {

                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $this->user_trailingslashit( '/wp-login-php/' );

            }

            require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

            die;

        }

        private function new_login_slug() {

            if ( ( $slug = get_option( 'rwl_page' ) )
                || ( is_multisite()
                    && is_plugin_active_for_network( $this->basename() )
                    && ( $slug = get_site_option( 'rwl_page', 'login' ) ) )
                || ( $slug = 'login' ) ) {

                return $slug;

            }

        }

        public function new_login_url( $scheme = null ) {

            if ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {

                return $this->user_trailingslashit( home_url( '/', $scheme ) . $this->new_login_slug() );

            }

            else {

                return home_url( '/', $scheme ) . '?' . $this->new_login_slug();

            }

        }

        public function __construct() {

            global $wp_version;

            register_activation_hook( $this->basename(), array( $this, 'activate' ) );
            register_uninstall_hook( $this->basename(), array( 'Secure_Login', 'uninstall' ) );

            add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'admin_notices' ) );
            add_action( 'network_admin_notices', array( $this, 'admin_notices' ) );

            if ( is_multisite()
                && ! function_exists( 'is_plugin_active_for_network' ) ) {

                require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

            }

            add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . $this->basename(), array( $this, 'plugin_action_links' ) );

            if ( is_multisite()
                && is_plugin_active_for_network( $this->basename() ) ) {

                add_filter( 'network_admin_plugin_action_links_' . $this->basename(), array( $this, 'plugin_action_links' ) );

                add_action( 'wpmu_options', array( $this, 'wpmu_options' ) );
                add_action( 'update_wpmu_options', array( $this, 'update_wpmu_options' ) );

            }

            add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'plugins_loaded' ), 1 );
            add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'wp_loaded' ) );

            add_filter( 'site_url', array( $this, 'site_url' ), 10, 4 );
            add_filter( 'network_site_url', array( $this, 'network_site_url' ), 10, 3 );
            add_filter( 'wp_redirect', array( $this, 'wp_redirect' ), 10, 2 );

            add_filter( 'site_option_welcome_email', array( $this, 'welcome_email' ) );

            remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );

        }

        public function activate() {

            add_option( 'rwl_redirect', '1' );

            delete_option( 'rwl_admin' );

        }

        public static function uninstall() {

            global $wpdb;

            if ( is_multisite() ) {

                $blogs = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT blog_id FROM {$wpdb->blogs}" );

                    if ( $blogs ) {

                        foreach( $blogs as $blog ) {

                            switch_to_blog( $blog );

                            delete_option( 'rwl_page' );

                        }

                        restore_current_blog();

                    }

                delete_site_option( 'rwl_page' );

            }

            else {

                delete_option( 'rwl_page' );

            }

        }

        public function wpmu_options() {

            $out = '';

            $out .= '<h3>Secure login location</h3>';
            $out .= '<p>This option allows you to set a networkwide default, which can be overridden by individual sites. Simply go to to the site’s permalink settings to change the url.</p>';
            $out .= '<table class="form-table">';
                $out .= '<tr valign="top">';
                    $out .= '<th scope="row">Networkwide default</th>';
                    $out .= '<td><input id="rwl-page-input" type="text" name="rwl_page" value="' . get_site_option( 'rwl_page', 'login' )  . '"></td>';
                $out .= '</tr>';
            $out .= '</table>';

            echo $out;

        }

        public function update_wpmu_options() {

            if ( ( $rwl_page = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $_POST['rwl_page'] ) )
                && strpos( $rwl_page, 'wp-login' ) === false
                && ! in_array( $rwl_page, $this->forbidden_slugs() ) ) {

                update_site_option( 'rwl_page', $rwl_page );

            }

        }

        public function admin_init() {

            global $pagenow;

            add_settings_section(
                'secure-login-section',
                'Admin url change',
                array( $this, 'rwl_section_desc' ),
                'permalink'
            );

            add_settings_field(
                'rwl-page',
                '<label for="rwl-page">Login url</label>',
                array( $this, 'rwl_page_input' ),
                'permalink',
                'secure-login-section'
            );

            if ( isset( $_POST['rwl_page'] )
                && $pagenow === 'options-permalink.php' ) {

                if ( ( $rwl_page = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $_POST['rwl_page'] ) )
                    && strpos( $rwl_page, 'wp-login' ) === false
                    && ! in_array( $rwl_page, $this->forbidden_slugs() ) ) {

                    if ( is_multisite() && $rwl_page === get_site_option( 'rwl_page', 'login' ) ) {

                        delete_option( 'rwl_page' );

                    }

                    else {

                        update_option( 'rwl_page', $rwl_page );

                    }

                }

            }

            if ( get_option( 'rwl_redirect' ) ) {

                delete_option( 'rwl_redirect' );

                if ( is_multisite()
                    && is_super_admin()
                    && is_plugin_active_for_network( $this->basename() ) ) {

                    $redirect = network_admin_url( 'settings.php#rwl-page-input' );

                }

                else {

                    $redirect = admin_url( 'options-permalink.php#rwl-page-input' );

                }

                wp_safe_redirect( $redirect );

                die;

            }

        }

        public function rwl_section_desc() {

            $out = '';

            if ( ! is_multisite()
                || is_super_admin() ) {

                $out .= '';

            }

            if ( is_multisite()
                && is_super_admin()
                && is_plugin_active_for_network( $this->basename() ) ) {

                $out .= '<p>To set a networkwide default, go to <a href="' . network_admin_url( 'settings.php#rwl-page-input' ) . '">Network Settings</a>.</p>';

            }

            echo $out;

        }

        public function rwl_page_input() {

            if ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {

                echo '<code>' . trailingslashit( home_url() ) . '</code> <input id="rwl-page-input" type="text" name="rwl_page" value="' . $this->new_login_slug()  . '">' . ( $this->use_trailing_slashes() ? ' <code>/</code>' : '' );

            }

            else {

                echo '<code>' . trailingslashit( home_url() ) . '?</code> <input id="rwl-page-input" type="text" name="rwl_page" value="' . $this->new_login_slug()  . '">';

            }

        }

        public function admin_notices() {

            global $pagenow;

            $out = '';

            if ( ! is_network_admin()
                && $pagenow === 'options-permalink.php'
                && isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {

                echo '<div class="updated"><p>Your login page is now here: <strong><a href="' . $this->new_login_url() . '">' . $this->new_login_url() . '</a></strong>. Bookmark this page!</p></div>';

            }

        }

        public function plugin_action_links( $links ) {

            if ( is_network_admin()
                && is_plugin_active_for_network( $this->basename() ) ) {

                array_unshift( $links, '<a href="' . network_admin_url( 'settings.php#rwl-page-input' ) . '">Settings</a>' );

            }

            elseif ( ! is_network_admin() ) {

                array_unshift( $links, '<a href="' . admin_url( 'options-permalink.php#rwl-page-input' ) . '">Settings</a>' );

            }

            return $links;

        }

        public function plugins_loaded() {

            global $pagenow;

            if ( ! is_multisite()
                && ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-signup' )  !== false
                    || strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-activate' ) )  !== false ) {

                wp_die( __( 'This feature is not enabled.' ) );

            }

            $request = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

            if ( ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-login.php' ) !== false
                    || untrailingslashit( $request['path'] ) === site_url( 'wp-login', 'relative' ) )
                && ! is_admin() ) {

                $this->wp_login_php = true;

                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $this->user_trailingslashit( '/' . str_repeat( '-/', 10 ) );

                $pagenow = 'index.php';

            }

            elseif ( untrailingslashit( $request['path'] ) === home_url( $this->new_login_slug(), 'relative' )
                || ( ! get_option( 'permalink_structure' )
                    && isset( $_GET[$this->new_login_slug()] )
                    && empty( $_GET[$this->new_login_slug()] ) ) ) {

                $pagenow = 'wp-login.php';

            }

        }

        public function wp_loaded() {

            global $pagenow;

            if ( is_admin()
                && ! is_user_logged_in()
                && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {

                wp_die( __( 'You must log in to access the admin area.' ) );

            }

            $request = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

            if ( $pagenow === 'wp-login.php'
                && $request['path'] !== $this->user_trailingslashit( $request['path'] )
                && get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {

                wp_safe_redirect( $this->user_trailingslashit( $this->new_login_url() )
                    . ( ! empty( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '' ) );

                die;

            }

            elseif ( $this->wp_login_php ) {

                if ( ( $referer = wp_get_referer() )
                    && strpos( $referer, 'wp-activate.php' ) !== false
                    && ( $referer = parse_url( $referer ) )
                    && ! empty( $referer['query'] ) ) {

                    parse_str( $referer['query'], $referer );

                    if ( ! empty( $referer['key'] )
                        && ( $result = wpmu_activate_signup( $referer['key'] ) )
                        && is_wp_error( $result )
                        && ( $result->get_error_code() === 'already_active'
                            || $result->get_error_code() === 'blog_taken' ) ) {

                        wp_safe_redirect( $this->new_login_url()
                            . ( ! empty( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '' ) );

                        die;

                    }

                }

                $this->wp_template_loader();

            }

            elseif ( $pagenow === 'wp-login.php' ) {

                global $error, $interim_login, $action, $user_login;

                @require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-login.php';

                die;

            }

        }

        public function site_url( $url, $path, $scheme, $blog_id ) {

            return $this->filter_wp_login_php( $url, $scheme );

        }

        public function network_site_url( $url, $path, $scheme ) {

            return $this->filter_wp_login_php( $url, $scheme );

        }

        public function wp_redirect( $location, $status ) {

            return $this->filter_wp_login_php( $location );

        }

        public function filter_wp_login_php( $url, $scheme = null ) {

            if ( strpos( $url, 'wp-login.php' ) !== false ) {

                if ( is_ssl() ) {

                    $scheme = 'https';

                }

                $args = explode( '?', $url );

                if ( isset( $args[1] ) ) {

                    parse_str( $args[1], $args );

                    $url = add_query_arg( $args, $this->new_login_url( $scheme ) );

                }

                else {

                    $url = $this->new_login_url( $scheme );

                }

            }

            return $url;

        }

        public function welcome_email( $value ) {

            return $value = str_replace( 'wp-login.php', trailingslashit( get_site_option( 'rwl_page', 'login' ) ), $value );

        }

        public function forbidden_slugs() {

            $wp = new WP;

            return array_merge( $wp->public_query_vars, $wp->private_query_vars );

        }

    }

    new Secure_Login;

}
```

Comment: Hello, stackoverflow its a helping and knowledge community, please can you provide more code comments and details about your functions and what it do?  Thanks @maulik-patel